# how Search in C# Universal

Tags: c#, search, universal

I have 10 file.txt in my app. and I want to search in this files and show to the user, I Use SearchBox In My Xaml.

I create Page For My Search Box, the page name: SearchResultsPage1, But I Don't Know Who Should I Search In My Files, And Show The Result To User (Or Show Result In My Page (SearchResultsPage1)),

Comment: Show (minimal relevant set of) code you have written so far. Currently your question is difficult to understand.

Comment: do those files contain any format(is data formatted)? so you can parse those files transform into objects and perform the search.

Comment: its text . in text file